# Why does this SQL work in one format, but not another?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've been having this problem with MySQL for the past month.  It's not a big problem, but it's pretty annoying.

```
 query = "SELECT * FROM MESSAGE_TEMPLATES WHERE MESSAGE_SEND_DATE = '" & _date & "'"
```

This simple line works fine when I pass it to the dataReader in MySQL.  However:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM MESSAGE_TEMPLATES" & _ 
" WHERE MESSAGE_SEND_DATE = '" & _date & "'"
```

This does not work, even though intellisense shows them both to have the same value.  MySQL complains about having an error in the syntax.  You can imagine this becomes more problematic for larger statements that take up several lines.  What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you print out each string to a console or a log and look for any random white space or involuntarily-included control characters?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, it's the way I have the string written.  In the case of the example I posted, it actually works fine (I grabbed a random string from the program).  However, in other cases, I did not add a space after the line break.

Answer (score 1):

It should work - can't be an MySQL thing as a strings a string.  If it persists consider using XML syntax to allow you to do the multi-line thing:

```
Dim query = <sql><![CDATA[
 SELECT * FROM MESSAGE_TEMPLATES
 WHERE MESSAGE_SEND_DATE = :Date
]]></sql>.Value
```

Also note that you should be using [parameterized queries](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/database-general-discussion/18562-ins-outs-parameterized-queries.html) as they are more secure easier to read and faster.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the parameterized queries.